# I want to make per server channels

Tags: python, json, discord.py

What i mean with 'per server' is that the channel is bound to a server
Here is the code i made:

```
def get_channel(client,message):
    with open('channels.json', 'r') as f:
        channels = json.load(f)
    return channels[str(message.guild.id)]

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('channels.json', 'r') as f:
        channels = json.load(f)
    channels[str(guild.id)] = ''
    with open('channels.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(channels,f)

@client.command()
async def cc(ctx, prefix):
    guild = ctx.guild
    with open('channels.json', 'r') as f:
        channels = json.load(f)
    channels[str(guild.id)] = prefix
    with open('channels.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(channels,f)
    await ctx.send('done')
```

This is the code where i put the function in

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name=get_channel)
    await channel.send(f'Welcome {member.mention}')
```

The text in the database is correct
The error i got:
await channel.send(f'Welcome {member.mention}')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Assuming this is about `discord.py` and tagging accordingly. Please edit if I'm wrong.

Comment: yeah it is about discord.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_channel(guild):
    with open('channels.json', 'r') as f:
        channels = json.load(f)
    return channels[str(guild.id)]

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('channels.json', 'r') as f:
        channels = json.load(f)
    channels[str(guild.id)] = ''
    with open('channels.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(channels,f)

@client.command()
async def channel_define(ctx, channel_name):
    guild = ctx.guild
    with open('channels.json', 'r') as f:
        channels = json.load(f)
    channels[str(guild.id)] = channel_name
    with open('channels.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(channels,f)
    await ctx.send('done')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name=get_channel(member.guild))
    await channel.send(f'Welcome {member.mention}')
```

This is the corrected version of the code. But I would advise you to register channel ids rather than names though.

If you want to use the get method with ids, refer to the doc : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.utils.get

Comment: NO WAY IT WORKED TY SO MUCH

Comment: I don't really want to ask this but how do you turn this into a method with ids?

Comment: In `channel_define`, you replace the `channel_name` option with `channel_id` (and give it a channel id rather than its name). Then, in `discord.utils.get`, you replace `name=func()` with `id=func()`.

Comment: it does not really work

Comment: Can you please send the code with id method

Comment: I have explained exactly how to do it, try to get to grips with the documentation and understand, it will be beneficial to you !

Comment: but i did exactly what you said

Answer (score 0):

```
channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='get_channel')
```

In this line you search for a channel, among the channels of the guild the member has joined, which has the name 'get_channel'. But the get function doesn't find any, so it returns None. This channel does not exist, or the cache is not loaded for this guild.

To load the cache of a guild :

```
await guild.chunk()
```

Comment: And where do i have to put the 'await guild.chunk()'?

Comment: Note: i changed the welcome code

Comment: Note: I forgot something and i added it

Comment: At the beginning of your vent, you can put :
`if not guild.chunked:
     await guild.chunk()`

But are you sure the problem isn't the name of the room you're looking for?

Comment: can you please look at my new code bcs that guild chunking doesnt work

Comment: You don't call your function correctly, to call it correctly you must put () and give the necessary arguments. But your function `get_channel` returns a list of str, and you only need one str (the name of the channel you want to find).

Comment: can you please send the new code that would be very nice i don't really understand it

Comment: I had misread, the function does not return a list. But I will post another answer with the correct code.

Comment: ok? do you know the answer?

Comment: The correct answer was posted above

Comment: but with id????

Comment: you replace `name=get_channel(member.guild)` with `id = channelid`
But you have to do it in other ways to find the channel id rather than the name

Comment: that doesn't really work

Comment: Can you please look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045316/why-does-my-bot-return-the-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attri/70045366?noredirect=1#comment123821500_70045366