# Why does my bot return the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'? Does someone have a solution?

Tags: python, discord

Hello i was making a discord bot that is for multiple servers and that can welcome everyone but if someone joins it gives the error:

await channel.send(f'Welcome {member.mention}')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

```
def get_welcome(guild):
    with open('welcomechannels.json', 'r') as f:
        welcomechannels = json.load(f)
    return welcomechannels[str(guild.id)]
        
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('welcomechannels.json', 'r') as f:
        welcomechannels = json.load(f)
    welcomechannels[str(guild.id)] = ''
    with open('welcomechannels.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(welcomechannels,f)

@client.command()
async def setwelcome(ctx, channel_id):
    guild = ctx.guild
    with open('welcomechannels.json', 'r') as f:
        welcomechannels = json.load(f)
    welcomechannels[str(guild.id)] = channel_id
    with open('welcomechannels.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(welcomechannels,f)
    await ctx.send('done')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, id=get_welcome(guild))
    await channel.send(f'Welcome {member.mention}')
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors is telling you that the variable `channel` is of the object type `None` and it does not have a `send` method. you are seeting the channel variable using this line

`channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, id=get_welcome(guild))`

The api docs for this get function detail its behaviour https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.utils.get

> discord.utils.get(iterable, **attrs) A helper that returns the first
> element in the iterable that meets all the traits passed in attrs.
> This is an alternative for find().
>
> When multiple attributes are specified, they are checked using logical
> AND, not logical OR. Meaning they have to meet every attribute passed
> in and not one of them.
>
> To have a nested attribute search (i.e. search by x.y) then pass in
> x__y as the keyword argument.
>
> **If nothing is found that matches the attributes passed, then None is returned.**

So in your case the attribute syo uhave passed are not finding anything so you get a None value returned which you store in channel. `None` doesnt have a send method you can call which is why you get the error.

Comment: And do you have a solution?

Comment: Well the solution solution put in attribute that result in you finding the channel. Can't really say any more than that as I don't know your server setup